# How to handle GET parameters in the proper Drupal way

Tags: 7

I am working on a module that will handle the email subscription functions for our newsletters.

Email newsletters are sent out to subscribers with a link on them for them to unsubscribe. This link is in the format `http://www.site.com/opt-out?email={email_address}`. This is how the links are formatted and I can't change that.

What is the proper way to deal with that parameter using Drupal? Of course I have access to `$_GET['email']`, but is this the proper way of accessing it in a Drupal module? What about input filtering? Should I just do a plain `$email = filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases, there are standard Drupal functions that do validation.  For example, for email addresses there is [valid_email_address](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/valid_email_address/7).

Otherwise, there is the standard PHP [Data Filtering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) library (many of the Drupal validation functions actually use this).

I am a little torn, though, on which to use when directly accessing `$_GET` or `$_POST`.  Lately, I have preferred using [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), because it can check that the variable exists and validate in one step, and because it also makes it easy to switch between the different input sources (URL parameters, cookies, etc) which can be handy at times.

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($email === NULL) $email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if ($email === FALSE) {
  handle_the_error();
} else {
  do_something_awesome();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When faced with this url structure,  you can use $_GET in the usual `PHP` way. Drupal urls are usually generated with parameters separated by `/`, and as you probably know,  [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) is the right tool when this is the case.

As for the email validation, there are native functions that validate, but the validation is quite basic:

```
//check if this is a valid Drupal username
user_validate_name('USERNAME');

//check if this is a valid email address
user_validate_mail('test@test.com');
```

If you had to do this in a form, one can add validation functions where needed with hook_form_alter:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)  {
 if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
  array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'email_check_validate');
 }
}

/**
 * Validate profile form
 * Force form error if new email address matches current email address
 *
 */
function email_check_validate ($form, $form_state)  {
  global $user;
  $old_email = $user->mail;
  $new_email = $form_state['values']['mail'];

  if ($old_email ==  $new_email) {
    form_set_error('mail', t('Your email could not be changed'));
  }
}
```

But this does not apply in your case, it was just an example for when you need to do validation through a form.

Hope this helps, cheers!